# Python: removing everything including and after a certain character on a line

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, string-formatting

I have some text like so:

```
1.6 # blah blah blah
# fjsadfklj slkjf yes 3.4
1.8*
1.9 1.10 #blah
#blah
1.11
```

I want to clean it up by removing all `#` characters plus anything following them on the same line. In other words, I desire:

```
1.6
1.8*
1.9 1.10
1.11
```

What is the best way to approach this? Via simple methods like `partition`, or maybe regexes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706198/python-how-to-ignore-comment-lines-when-reading-in-a-file
Note that the best answer is not the top-rated, probably look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27178714/2284490 for the most robust answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this,

```
re.sub(r'\s*#.*', '', s)
```

`\s*` will helps to match also the preceding vertical or horizontal space character. What I mean by vertical space is newline character , carriage return.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mH6wP2/1)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this does what you want it to do in fulfilling your request?

```
example = '''1.6 # blah blah blah
# fjsadfklj slkjf yes 3.4
1.8*
1.9 1.10 #blah
#blah
1.11'''

for line in example.splitlines():
    print(line.split('#', 1)[0])
```

If you really want the comment text, the code is easily modifiable to allows its capture as well.

Comment: This is the superior method because it is simple and explicit.

Comment: A naive `timeit` shows split is also ~4x as fast.  `python -m timeit 'strs = ("x"*(100 - i%101) + "#" + "y"*100 for i in xrange(10000)); import re' 'for s in strs: re.sub(r"\s*#.*", "", s)'` vs `s.split("#", 1)[0]`.  31.5 msec vs 7.02 msec on my machine